# Elasticsearch, index manteinance / deleting documents from a big index

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk

I need to delete documents that have a "date" field older than one year from a 10 million documents index. This should be done a first time to purge a lot of documents, than daily as mainteninace routine.

The date field in the mapping is a classic datetime :

```
"date" : {
        "type" : "date",
        "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
      }
```

Index weights 24.5 gb and the document is very simple (id, date, ip address and little else) and i don't know what is the best way to proceed in such a situation.

My cluster is running on Elasticsearch 6.8.14

Should i download it (ie using elasticdump) and work on the index locally, delete the unwanted documents with an homemade script and reload it on the cluster ?

Or is there a tool that i can use in production that I can use daily and will align the index and keep it constantly with documents not older than a year ?

Comment: You could use the index lifecycle & rollovers that elastic has. Recommend you look into those, the latest version of Elastic makes it easy, in older versions, you will have to call the API manually. There was also a tool for the 5.6 version called curator that can do it, that is if you are still running such an old version. Recommend you add those details when asking the question.

Comment: I would definitely move to time-based indices and delete older indices instead of using delete-by-query as using it on a regular basis on a big index will put too much strain on your index.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning - My cluster is based on ES 6.8.14   - Unfortunately I cannot move to time-based indices, at least not in a short time. I am aware that deleting by query on such an index is very heavy, that's why I thought to perform the first cleanup "offline". However thank you - I wil dig deeper inside index lifecycle & rollovers + curator. Any additional useful tip will be really appreciated !